# change the color of certain data points in r

Tags: r

I was wondering that how I can change the color of certain data points in a scatter plot in R?

So, for example, I want the data point in the 7th, 8th, and 15th row to have a red color and the rest have a black color.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This is pretty easy to do. We can even show you, if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As you will find in these two links, you should "show your work", and "Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, [and] why they didn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?

```
randomdata<-    
data.frame(x=1:20,y=rnorm(20,8,1),col=as.character("black"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
randomdata[c(7,8,15),"col"]<-"red"
plot(randomdata$x,randomdata$y,col=randomdata$col)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work given that you data is in a `data.frame` called "dat".

```
cols <- rep('black', nrow(dat))
cols[c(7, 8, 15)] <- 'red'
```

In your plot command set `col = cols`.